# GCD and congruence proof

Tags: congruences, gcd-and-lcm

> If $gcd(a,m)=1$ then there is a $b$ such that $ab \equiv 1 \pmod m$

I came across this statement in my review sheet for an upcoming midterm, I tried looking it up and in my notes but couldn't find anything like this. Does this statement have a name? Or can someone link me to a proof? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is recalling that $\gcd(a, m) = 1 \implies \exists b, c \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $ab + mc = 1$.

Can you see how to finish up?

---

As a side note, the integers $b$ and $c$ can be found explicitly using the [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm).

Comment: Yes. $ab-1=cm$ which is $ab \equiv 1 \pmod m$, right?

Comment: Indeed!  Technically the first step there isn't required and you can arrive at the conclusion immediately by modding out the original equation by $m$.

Comment: The result used in the proof is known as [Bézout's Identity](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity)